# Need Recycle Bin Folder Name

Tags: api, delphi

I need to know the recycle Bin Folder name so that I can empty it thru my Delphi Seattle application. I have used below code without any success. Same code works for other Folders like CSIDL_COOKIES , CSIDL_RECENT etc. but somehow CSIDL_BITBUCKET does not give any output.

```
function GetWinSysFolders(FolderTpye:Integer):String;
var
  Allocator: IMalloc;
  SpecialDir: PItemIdList;
  FBuf: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
  PerDir: string;
begin
  if SHGetMalloc(Allocator) = NOERROR then
  begin    // form1.Handle      v
    SHGetSpecialFolderLocation( 0, FolderTpye, SpecialDir);
    SHGetPathFromIDList(SpecialDir, @FBuf[0]);
    Allocator.Free(SpecialDir);
    result:=string(FBuf);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Can't you use `SHEmptyRecycleBin` function in `Shell32.dll` to empty recycle bin?

Comment: Even if you did need to get the folder path (which you don't), you should have been using `SHGetFolderPath()` instead, then you don't need to use `SHGetPathFromIDList()` or `IMalloc` (you should have been using `CoTaskMemFree()` instead of `IMalloc` directly)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not able to get a filesystem path for `CSIDL_BITBUCKET` because it simply does not have a single filesystem path to begin with - the "Recycle Bin" as you think of it is actually a virtual folder in the Shell. Every drive has its own physical bin storage, and `CSIDL_BITBUCKET` represents the virtual folder that encompasses all of the individual drive bins as a single entity in the Shell.

Also, the "Recycle Bin" contains metadata about each deleted file, such as which user it belongs to, where it was deleted from, etc.  As such, you can't interact with the contents of `CSIDL_BITBUCKET` at the filesystem level (not without corrupting it, anyway). You need to use the Shell interfaces instead. See Raymond Chen's blog articles on [How can I get information about the items in the Recycle Bin?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110830-00/?p=9773) and [Invoking commands on items in the Recycle Bin](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110901-00/?p=9753) for more details.  For instance, you can use the Shell interfaces to enumerate the files in the "Recycle Bin" and invoke the `"delete"` verb on each desired file as needed.

That being said, the Win32 API has a simple [`SHEmptyRecycleBin()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shemptyrecyclebinw) function to empty files from a specified drive's bin.  Use that function instead of emptying the "Recycle Bin" manually.

Comment: This can't be quite right. Recycle bin has to be per user as well as per drive.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The physical storage is per-drive (ie, such as in ```C:\$Recycle.Bin```), but per-user items are stored inside of each drive's bin (ie, as a subfolder for each user).

Comment: Right, that's what I said

Comment: Thank You for the elaborate explanation. I had wasted hours trying to Locate recycle bin. SHEmptyRecycleBin() does the job.